# Correct Subsetting Solution

Tags: r

I have two data frames clust1 and clust2 with the different number of rows. clust1 has 53 rows and clust2 has 150 rows. I would like to subset the items to identify the row items in clust2 that have the similar longitude and latitude of clust1.

If I write this code:

```
a <- subset(clust2, clust2$Pickup_longitude == clust1$Pickup_longitude)
```

I will occur the below error:

```
Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

If I write in this way:

```
a <- subset(clust2, clust2[53,]$Pickup_longitude == clust1$Pickup_longitude)
```

I will get the answer but definitely, my answer is wrong as I have limited the number of rows in clust2. what should I do to get the proper answer?

Comment: have you tried using %in% instead of ==?

Comment: Try `merge(clust1, clust2, by = Pickup_longitude)`

Comment: It would help to post sample data of `clust1` and `clust2` and expected output `a` so we can provide working solutions.

Comment: @Gopala: In this question data structure is not important.

Comment: You can use the following as data Frames `clust1 = data.frame (Pickup_longitude = c(1,2,3,4,5), lat = c(1,2,3,4,5))
clust2 = data.frame (Pickup_longitude = c(1,3,7), lat = c(1,3,7))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use dplyr's semi_join().

```
library(dplyr)
a <- semi_join(clust2, clust1, by = "Pickup_longitude")
```

That should give you all rows in clust2 that have Pickup_longitude values that appear in clust1.

(Edited to add the quotes in the "by" - thanks Gopala)

Comment: I got this error "object 'Pickup_longitude' not found
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection."

Comment: It has to be in 'quotes'.

Comment: @Adrian what is wrong with b <- semi_join(clustd2, clustp1, by = c("Pickup_longitude","Pickup_latitude")). I got errorfor this code.

Comment: In general it's easier to diagnose when you post the error. But I think it might be fixed if you say: "semi_join(clustd2, clustp1, by = c("Pickup_longitude" = "Pickup_longitude", "Pickup_latitude" = "Pickup_latitude")

Answer (score 1):

[Sarina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2742936/sarina) comment will work, you just need to:

```
a <- subset(clust2, clust2$Pickup_longitude %in% clust1$Pickup_longitude)
```

I also suggest, as you asked, if you want to identify the rows that have the similar longitude and latitude you can use `which()`:

```
which(clust2$Pickup_longitude %in% clust1$Pickup_longitude)
```

This will give you the row numbers in clust2 that have the same long in clust1.

Comment: Thanks it works but I have doubt about the result. In your section (in the which statement), you used Pickup_longitude only. how to use both longitude and latitude both in which statement

Comment: We would need a reproducible example of your data to check this, this will match only if the values are exactly the same. To check similar values you can round the numbers given a number of decimal places.

Comment: If you want to use longitude and latitude you could use the following command `which(clust2$Pickup_longitude %in% clust1$Pickup_longitude& clust2$Pickup_latitude %in% clust1$Pickup_latitude)` assuming that your column with the latitude has the name "Pickup_latitude" in correspondence with the longitude. The same can be done in the subset function. However this is still not doing "similar" lat&longs but only identical